# Timeline graph - how to handle "time gaps"?

Tags: api, graph, charts, timeline

I've been working with Google chart API and annotated timeline. Drawing graphs is fine. I have no problem.

However, I need to draw a timeline graph for share prices. And as you may know, share prices are meaningful only between certain times (e.g. from 10AM to 4PM, when the market opens and closes).

How do I change the Google timeline graph so that on X-Axis, the range is from 10AM-4PM? Right now, it just draws a long constant line between 4PM till 10AM next day before prices start to move again.

Man, I hope that makes sens. (Google finance chart seems to do it).

Thank you SO much for whoever can answer. You are a CHAMPION!

Comment: Maybe you could add a couple of screenshots to clarify your problem

Comment: and/or the code you are having now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparently now possible if you use the new AnnotationChart API: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=25#c43

You could also use other, similar solutions, like [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After giving it a little though I found workaround. Just fill the missing values with 0 (or null) values. It will do the job